# Unable to debug Xamarin on Android emulator with message: The debug was canceled. Please create an Android emulator

Tags: c#, android, debugging, xamarin, android-emulator

Unable to debug XAmarin on Android emulator. When trying to start the debugger I receive this error in the "Output" window :

> The debug was canceled. Please create an android emulator to debug the
>   application.

But I already have an Android emulator running (Pixel 2 Pie 9.0) that I already used to debug another Xamarin project with success. I restarted my machine and retry only with my current project and got the same behavior.

This application is only a blank Android Project with no change.

As as side note (note sure if it is related). When I press the button "Apply Android Resource changes and restart activity". The final message in the status bar is:

> Deploying resource changes failed. Couldn't list apks for package:
>   [Package name]

I have no idea what to do? Any idea?

Comment: Can you try to uninstall Android emulator(Pixel 2 Pie 9.0) and install this android emulator again, then run your project using this Android emulator, or you can also run your project on another android emulator and see if it can works or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-install VS2019 and everything works.

By the way, I installed some old Android SDK just before the problem happen. Related???